# Basic Auth and Grant Type for OAuth 2 in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, basic-authentication

I have a Spring Boot application using OAuth2 and JWT for authentication. In my `application-development.yml`, I have the following configuration:

```
security:
  jwt:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: mySecretPassword1
    key-pair-alias: clientId
    key-pair-password: mySecretPassword1
```

And in my `AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java`, I have:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer authorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) throws Exception {
    authorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
            .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .exceptionTranslator(webResponseExceptionTranslator)
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/login");
}
```

Using this, I can login to the system using Postman. But, everytime I need to login, in Postman, I need to configure the client id and client secret for basic auth and grant types as shown in the screenshots below:

[Basic Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bR0p.png)

[Grant Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLwlU.png)

I need to be able to login without providing the clientId, clientSecret and grant_type everytime.

I have seen something similar done in case of microservices using cloud config as shown below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true

      routes:
        - id: auth-service
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/auth/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/auth/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: auth-service
          uri: lb://auth-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/login/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/login(?<path>.*), /oauth/token$\{path}
            - AddRequestHeader=Authorization,Basic BaS!CAuthT0ken
            - AddRequestParameter=grant_type,password
```

Here, the filters are added inside gateway, and it works perfectly fine. I need a way to replicate the same in case of a Monolith without using gateway. I need a way to replace the following code:

```
- AddRequestHeader=Authorization,Basic BaS!CAuthT0ken
- AddRequestParameter=grant_type,password
```

I've tried using the following in my AuthorizationServerConfiguration:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clientDetailsServiceConfigurer) throws Exception {
    clientDetailsServiceConfigurer.jdbc(this.dataSource)
            .withClient("clientId")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .secret(encoder().encode("mySecretPassword1"))
            .scopes("read","write");
```

But I have found no success as it results in the following error:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ehrm so you want security but you don't want security because you do't want to provide the credentials?

Comment: I don't want the client to need to enter the client id and secret everytome from the client side. I want to handle this in the backend itself. Any thoughts on this?